# My website appears zoomed in when I try to access it on a mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've developed a website and have made it responsive too but the problem is that even after making the website responsive by  adding respective media queries my website is still not perfect for mobiles as its width is larger than the mobile viewport i.e. it is [accessed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVu25.jpg). So I need to zoom out to get the desired view. I've tried everything
like

- making the container's width 100%
- setting it's width as relative
- the meta tag is also correct in order to make a website responsive

and so on but all in vain.
This is one of the code snippet for reference.

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".burgerLines");
let menu = document.querySelector(".mobileNavBar");

let navName = document.querySelector(".navName");

let btnOpened = false;

function burgerMenuToggle() {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle("menuOpened");
  menu.classList.toggle("mobileNavBarOpened");
  navName.classList.toggle("navNameInMobNavBar");

  if (!btnOpened) {
    //     menuBtn.classList.add("menuOpened");
    //     menu.classList.add("mobileNavBarOpened");
    //     navName.classList.add("navNameInMobNavBar");

    // console.log("burgerMenuToggle's if part executed");

    menu.style.transform = "translate(590px, 20px)";
    menu.style.opacity = "1";
    btnOpened = true;

  } else {
    //     menuBtn.classList.remove("menuOpened");
    //     menu.classList.remove("mobileNavBarOpened");
    //     navName.classList.remove("navNameInMobNavBar");

    // console.log("burgerMenuToggle's else part executed");

    menu.style.transform = "translate(590px, -370px)";
    menu.style.opacity = "0";
    btnOpened = false;
  }
}
```

```css
  .menuButton {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 77, 148, 0);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.burgerLines {
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(255, 77, 148);
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(255, 77, 148);
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.burgerLines::before,
.burgerLines::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(255, 77, 148);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.burgerLines::before {
  transform: translate(0, -17px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.burgerLines::after {
  transform: translate(0, 2px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.burgerLines.menuOpened {
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.burgerLines.menuOpened::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(28px, -36px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.burgerLines.menuOpened::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(39px, 25px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.heroSection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 70%, rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.navigationBar {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.navigationBar>a:not(.navName) {
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#contactMeButton {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

#contactMeButton:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
  color: white;
}

.mobileNavBarOpened {
  /* The CSS transition of transform and opacity is being controlled thru JS */
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.03, 0.21, 0.99);
}

.mobileNavBar {
  width: 250px;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 75px 0px 50px 35px;
  transform: translate(595px, -370px);
  background: rgb(126, 110, 219);
  background: linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(19, 0, 129, 1) 25%, rgba(15, 197, 198, 1) 75%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.03, 0.21, 0.99);
}

.mobileNavBar>div>a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobileNavBar>div>a::first-letter {
  font-size: larger;
  color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
}

.mobileNavBar>div>a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navName {
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-right: 605px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.03, 0.21, 0.99);
}

.navNameInMobNavBar {
  transform: translate(575px, 8px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.navName::first-letter {
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
}

.circleOfImage {
  border: 0px solid white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -150px auto;
  background-image: url(media/heroSection/myImage.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 13px 13px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.circleOfImage:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px white;
}

.name {
  margin: 58px auto 0px auto;
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  transition: text-shadow 0.5s;
}

.name:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgb(255, 77, 148);
}

.subHeading {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 150px auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  transition: text-shadow 0.5s;
}

.subHeading:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navigationBar>a>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 77, 148);
  color: rgb(255, 77, 148);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.scrollDownText {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.instagram,
.twitter,
.tele {
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.navigationBar>a::after,
.scrollDownText::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgb(255, 77, 148);
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.5s;
}

.navigationBar>a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}


/* So that the contact button in the navigation bar doesn't have a bottom border beneath it when hovered */

.navigationBar>a:nth-of-type(7)::after {
  width: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 770px) {
  .heroSection {
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .heroSection>nav>a:not(.navName) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigationBar>a {
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.03, 0.21, 0.99);
  }
  .navName {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .menuButton {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate(585px);
  }
  .circleOfImage {
    margin: -150px 323px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&family=Satisfy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="heroSection">
  <nav class="navigationBar">
    <a href="" class="navName"> Mohammed </a>
    <a href=""> Home </a>
    <a href="#aboutMeImg"> About </a>
    <a href="#expertise"> Skills </a>
    <a download="Resume_Mohammed_Bhanpurawala" href="resume.pdf"> Resume </a>
    <!-- <a href=""> Portfolio </a>
                <a href=""> Blog </a> -->
    <a href="mailto:bhanpurawalamohammed96@gmail.com"> Contact </a>
    <a href="mailto:bhanpurawalamohammed96@gmail.com">
      <button id="contactMeButton" type="button">
                        Contact Me
                    </button>
    </a>

    <button class="menuButton" onclick="burgerMenuToggle()">
                    <div class="burgerLines">

                    </div>
                </button>

  </nav>

  <div class="mobileNavBar">

    <div id="home">
      <a href="https://mohammedbhanpurawala.great-site.net/">
                        Home
                    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="about">
      <a href="#discoverId">
                        About
                    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="skills">
      <a href="#expertise">
                        Skills
                    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="resume">
      <a download="Resume_Mohammed_Bhanpurawala" href="resume.pdf">
                        Resume
                    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
      <a href="mailto:bhanpurawalamohammed96@gmail.com">
                        Contact
                    </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Centre Image in Circle -->
  <div class="circleOfImage"></div>

  <div class="name"> Mohammed Bhanpurawala </div>

  <div class="subHeading"> A Creative Developer &amp; a Passionate Learner </div>

  <a href="#discoverId" class="scrollDownTextLink">
    <div class="scrollDownText">
      Scroll Down
      <img src="media/heroSection/scrollDownImg.png" alt="scrollDownImg" height="25" width="25">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Could anyone please help me by letting me know where I'm wrong  and what needs to get alterned in order to make its width relative to  the viewport of the device?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Question has been rectified

Answer (score 0):

You are using `px` in your css, which is not device friendly. As a good practice use `em`, `rem` for same as they will do same job but with relative to parent element.
Also, Please add metadata for viewport, which will auto adjust your application as per device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code had bugs that I fixed...

And I commented on the places I deleted to make your design somewhat responsive.
Of course, there is still a lot of work to be done to complete your project, which is up to you .
good luck

`css code :` 
https://codepen.io/amin-da/pen/WNOEKpK?editors=0100